# Add new parameter to url with /

Tags: php

I take this function to add parameter to url:

```
function addToUrl($url, $key, $value = null) {
    $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    if ($query) {
        parse_str($query, $queryParams);
        $queryParams[$key] = $value;
        $url = str_replace("?$query", '?' . http_build_query($queryParams), $url);
    } else {
        $url .= '?' . urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value);
    }
    return $url;
}
```

This work. But not for all URL. I have this sample url:

```
1. http://www.google.de
2. http://www.google.de/
3. http://www.google.de/index.html
4. http://www.google.de/?otherParameter=test
```

The second example is the only who don't work. He make: http://www.google.de?parameter=... But i will have this: http://www.google.de/?parameter=...

The function replace the space with +. is this correct? is the right not %20?

Comment: To encode a blank character ("space") with a plus sign (`+`) is correct.

Comment: why you don't just check if url has a / at the end remove it. both "+" and "%20" works

Comment: For the rest it is unclear what you actually ask. All four example URLs look fine from a syntactical point of view. If the work on your site depends in the rewriting rules you have in place. But that is nothing php is responsible for.

Comment: ok Thank you. Is http://www.google.de/?otherParameter=test and http://www.google.de?otherParameter=test the same? Is the / not necessary?